# Create data frame from lists that are uneven

Tags: r

My code below is me scraping data from IMDB from multiple pages, however, when I try to combine the data into one data frame it is giving me an error telling me the differing rows for gross and meta. I was wondering how would I go about inserting NA values to those empty places so the strings are equal in length?  (Note, I have to remove some links because I need certain rep to post more links)

```
urls <- c("https://www.imdb.com/search/title?title_type=feature&release_date=2010-01-01,2017-12-31",
              "https://www.imdb.com/search/title?title_type=feature&release_date=2010-01-01,2017-12-31&start=51&ref_=adv_nxt",
              "https://www.imdb.com/search/title?title_type=feature&release_date=2010-01-01,2017-12-31&start=101&ref_=adv_nxt",
              "https://www.imdb.com/search/title?title_type=feature&release_date=2010-01-01,2017-12-31&start=151&ref_=adv_nxt",
              "https://www.imdb.com/search/title?title_type=feature&release_date=2010-01-01,2017-12-31&start=201&ref_=adv_nxt",
              "https://www.imdb.com/search/title?title_type=feature&release_date=2010-01-01,2017-12-31&start=251&ref_=adv_nxt",
              "https://www.imdb.com/search/title?title_type=feature&release_date=2010-01-01,2017-12-31&start=301&ref_=adv_nxt",
              "https://www.imdb.com/search/title?title_type=feature&release_date=2010-01-01,2017-12-31&start=351&ref_=adv_nxt",
              "https://www.imdb.com/search/title?title_type=feature&release_date=2010-01-01,2017-12-31&start=401&ref_=adv_nxt",
              "https://www.imdb.com/search/title?title_type=feature&release_date=2010-01-01,2017-12-31&start=451&ref_=adv_nxt",
              "https://www.imdb.com/search/title?title_type=feature&release_date=2010-01-01,2017-12-31&start=501&ref_=adv_nxt",
              "https://www.imdb.com/search/title?title_type=feature&release_date=2010-01-01,2017-12-31&start=551&ref_=adv_nxt",
              "https://www.imdb.com/search/title?
              )


    results_list <- list()

    for(.page in seq_along(urls)){
      webpage <- read_html(urls[[.page]])
      titlehtml <- html_nodes(webpage,'.lister-item-header a')
      title <- html_text(titlehtml)
      runtimehtml <- html_nodes(webpage,'.text-muted .runtime')
      runtime <- html_text(runtimehtml)
      runtime <- gsub(" min","",runtime)
      ratinghtml <- html_nodes(webpage,'.ratings-imdb-rating strong')
      rating<- html_text(ratinghtml)
      voteshtml <- html_nodes(webpage,'.sort-num_votes-visible span:nth-child(2)')
      votes <- html_text(voteshtml)
      votes<-gsub(",","",votes)#removing commas
      metascorehtml <- html_nodes(webpage,'.metascore')
      metascore <- html_text(metascorehtml)
      metascore<-gsub(" ","",metascore)#removing extra space in metascore
      grosshtml <- html_nodes(webpage,'.ghost~ .text-muted+ span')
      gross <- html_text(grosshtml)
      gross<-gsub("M","",gross)#removing '$' and 'M' signs
      gross<-substring(gross,2,6)

      results_list[[.page]] <- data.frame(Title = title,
                                          Runtime = as.numeric(runtime),
                                          Rating = as.numeric(rating),
                                          Metascore = as.numeric(metascore), 
                                          Votes = as.numeric(votes), 
                                          Gross_Earning_in_Mil = as.numeric(unlist(gross))
                                          )
    }

    final_results <- plyr::ldply(results_list)

    Error in data.frame(Title = title, Runtime = as.numeric(runtime), Rating = as.numeric(rating),  : 
      arguments imply differing number of rows: 50, 49, 48
```

Comment: When one vector is of length 50 and another is of 49, where do you want `NA` to be? Always at the end? I guess not.

Comment: I want it to be where the value is supposed to be

Comment: And where is it supposed to be?

Comment: Now I realize maybe always at the end will be easier to work with!

Comment: That's indeed much easier to achieve. I guess ideally you would really want it to be at the "right" place, just I think that finding the right place is a much more difficult question than creating a data frame from unequal vectors.

Comment: If you just insert `NA` at the end of each vector your data will be wrong, you definitely don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know where your data is missing, so you need to know which items belong together. Right now you just have seperate vectors of values, so you don't know which belong together.

Looking at the page, it looks they are neatly organized into "lister-item-content"-nodes, so the clean thing to do is first extract those nodes, and only then pull out more info from each unit seperately. Something like this works for me:

```
items <- html_nodes(webpage,'.lister-item-content')
gross <- sapply(items, function(i) {html_text(html_node(i, '.ghost~ .text-muted+ span'))})
```

It inserts NA at every place where 'items' does not contain the header you're looking for.